# Unable to load class 'ijinit_dkec9zswd4p83aajh1klyj0h5'. (React_native gradle sync issue)

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle

**Unable to load class 'ijinit_dkec9zswd4p83aajh1klyj0h5'. (React_native gradle sync issue)**

I am facing this issue on Gradle sync while building .apk, dubug apk is working fine.

I have also cleaned Gradle and rebuilt my app but still no improvement.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPjMu.png)

**Build Script:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Unable to load class 'ijinit_dkec9zswd4p83aajh1klyj0h5'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not load compiled classes for initialization script 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle' from cache.

> ijinit_dkec9zswd4p83aajh1klyj0h5

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not load compiled classes for initialization script 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle' from cache.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ijinit_dkec9zswd4p83aajh1klyj0h5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update will solve your problem

`Help` -> `Check for Updates`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error, fixed it by upgrading Android Studio. It needed a proper sync after upgrade.

Refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36990380